# How do I get my lost space hamster back?

Tags: mass-effect-3

My cabin just doesn't feel the same without my little space hamster friend to keep me company. I've heard that if you bought the space hamster in Mass Effect 2 and import your save into Mass Effect 3, the little guy can be found running around the Normandy somewhere. It sounds too good to be true.

**How do I get my lost space hamster back?**

Sub-questions:

- If I didn't import my save from Mass Effect 2, is there still a way to get the space hamster in Mass Effect 3?
- Does he need to be taken care of like my fish?
- Does having the space hamster change anything in this game (i.e. give rewards, change the story slightly, etc.)?

Comment: Finally, a question that covers the most important aspect of the mass effect series

Comment: You see him the first time you visit Jack's old room, but I wasn't able to catch him and I haven't seen him since.

Comment: @SteveV. He's there. Just wait a minute and he'll run around again.

Comment: @SteveV. I didn't spot and pick him up until after Tuchanka, and I 'd been down to that area after most missions just to check nothing's going on (specially after I caught that Prothean poking around in the under-belly of engineering), so he's definitely there for a while and not just one-time thing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can totally find your space hamster, specifically in the engineering deck:

It would appear that the answer to your sub-questions is "No" for all three:

- [This wiki entry](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Space_Hamster) says you need the ME2 save
- [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9w-5OEQK8A) shows some more interaction with the hamster towards the end and I don't see anything indicating you can do more than hear him squeak.

Comment: according to the [wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Save_File_Transfer#Character_Transfer) he's capturable: One will need to position Shepard along the hamster's path in order to grab it and place it back in its cage in the Captain's quarters.

Comment: @yx. Yes, the video makes that clear.  By "if you catch him please let us know the details!" I meant the details about how you can interact with it after catching it.

Comment: if you do catch him he goes back into the cage in your cabin and behaves exactly like he did in ME2